# if else in jq is not giving expected output

Tags: jq

I need to display users if their realm is internal.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "name": "A_A",
    "uri": "https:test/test",
    "realm": "internal"
  },
  {
    "name": "B_B",
    "uri": "https:test/test",
    "realm": "internal"
  },
  {
    "name": "C_C",
    "uri": "https:test/test",
    "realm": "external"
  }
]
```

Tried with:

```
jq 'if .[].realm == "internal" then .[].name else empty end'
```

But the problem is that it is listing all the users.

Expected output:

```
A_A , B_B
```

Comment: I would look at the Elastic search syntax, if you are talking to one. I am not exactly on expert on that, I often do my queries though trial and error, so not the best person to write an answer.

Comment: `.[] | (if .realm == "internal" then .name else empty end)`. You have to put your conditional **after** you iterated into the individual item you want to test.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the jq function `select`:

```
<file jq -r '.[] | select(.realm == "internal") | .name'
```

The first `.[]` gets the array elements. The `select()` applies to individual element and filter the ones have the correct `realm`. The last part prints the `name` field.

Comment: If you'd rather have an array, use `map(select(.realm == "internal") | .name)` instead. That would let you `| join(delim)` with a specific delimiter if you need to  : [here](https://jqplay.org/s/8pnVVfyNek)'s a sample with your exact expected output

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your conditional **after** you iterated into the individual item you want to test.

```
jq '.[]| (if .realm == "internal" then .name else empty end)'
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the user wants CSV formatted output, so I'm just giving an alternative solution that shows how you may do that with the `@csv` output operator in `jq`.

This command also uses `map()` to apply the `select()` statement to each of the elements of the input array.

```bash
$ jq -r 'map(select(.realm == "internal").name)|@csv' file
"A_A","B_B"
```

This shows that I have approached the issue by selecting the relevant array entries based on the `realm` key's value and then extracting the value of the `name` key from these. This leaves us with an array of `name` values, which `@csv` formats and outputs as a single CSV record.